# Can't set the font on a SKLabelNode in tvOS

Tags: objective-c, fonts, sprite-kit, tvos, apple-tv

I'm having an issue when I try to instantiate an *SKLabelNode* with any font under **tvOS**. I use the following based on the documentation ([here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKLabelNode_Ref/)):

```
SKLabelNode *label = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];
```

However, the font does not change and the default font is used. Am I missing something?

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT:**

Apparently some iOS fonts are not available at this time on tvOS. In case it helps anyone here is a list of fonts that can be used at the moment:

```
Kohinoor Telugu: (
    "KohinoorTelugu-Light",
    "KohinoorTelugu-Medium",
    "KohinoorTelugu-Regular"
)
Heiti SC: (
)
Symbol: (
    Symbol
)
Courier: (
    "Courier-BoldOblique",
    Courier,
    "Courier-Bold",
    "Courier-Oblique"
)
Avenir Next: (
    "AvenirNext-DemiBold",
    "AvenirNext-UltraLight",
    "AvenirNext-Regular",
    "AvenirNext-HeavyItalic",
    "AvenirNext-BoldItalic",
    "AvenirNext-MediumItalic",
    "AvenirNext-Italic",
    "AvenirNext-Heavy",
    "AvenirNext-DemiBoldItalic",
    "AvenirNext-Bold",
    "AvenirNext-UltraLightItalic",
    "AvenirNext-Medium"
)
Arial Hebrew: (
    "ArialHebrew-Light",
    ArialHebrew,
    "ArialHebrew-Bold"
)
Telugu Sangam MN: (
)
Helvetica Neue: (
    "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight",
    "HelveticaNeue-UltraLightItalic",
    "HelveticaNeue-LightItalic",
    HelveticaNeue,
    "HelveticaNeue-Light",
    "HelveticaNeue-MediumItalic",
    "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold",
    "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack",
    "HelveticaNeue-Thin",
    "HelveticaNeue-ThinItalic",
    "HelveticaNeue-Medium",
    "HelveticaNeue-Italic",
    "HelveticaNeue-BoldItalic",
    "HelveticaNeue-Bold"
)
Trebuchet MS: (
    "TrebuchetMS-Italic",
    "TrebuchetMS-Bold",
    "Trebuchet-BoldItalic",
    TrebuchetMS
)
Bangla Sangam MN: (
)
Heiti TC: (
)
Hiragino Sans: (
    "HiraginoSans-W6",
    "HiraginoSans-W3"
)
Tamil Sangam MN: (
    TamilSangamMN,
    "TamilSangamMN-Bold"
)
PingFang TC: (
    "PingFangTC-Semibold",
    "PingFangTC-Medium",
    "PingFangTC-Regular",
    "PingFangTC-Ultralight",
    "PingFangTC-Light",
    "PingFangTC-Thin"
)
Times New Roman: (
    "TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT",
    "TimesNewRomanPS-BoldItalicMT",
    TimesNewRomanPSMT,
    "TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT"
)
Kohinoor Devanagari: (
    "KohinoorDevanagari-Light",
    "KohinoorDevanagari-Regular",
    "KohinoorDevanagari-Semibold"
)
Kohinoor Bangla: (
    "KohinoorBangla-Regular",
    "KohinoorBangla-Semibold",
    "KohinoorBangla-Light"
)
Thonburi: (
    Thonburi,
    "Thonburi-Bold",
    "Thonburi-Light"
)
Gujarati Sangam MN: (
    "GujaratiSangamMN-Bold",
    GujaratiSangamMN
)
Geeza Pro: (
    "GeezaPro-Bold",
    GeezaPro
)
Lao Sangam MN: (
    LaoSangamMN
)
Sinhala Sangam MN: (
    "SinhalaSangamMN-Bold",
    SinhalaSangamMN
)
Courier New: (
    CourierNewPSMT,
    "CourierNewPS-BoldItalicMT",
    "CourierNewPS-BoldMT",
    "CourierNewPS-ItalicMT"
)
Malayalam Sangam MN: (
    MalayalamSangamMN,
    "MalayalamSangamMN-Bold"
)
PingFang SC: (
    "PingFangSC-Regular",
    "PingFangSC-Ultralight",
    "PingFangSC-Thin",
    "PingFangSC-Medium",
    "PingFangSC-Light",
    "PingFangSC-Semibold"
)
Apple SD Gothic Neo: (
    "AppleSDGothicNeo-Thin",
    "AppleSDGothicNeo-SemiBold",
    "AppleSDGothicNeo-Light",
    "AppleSDGothicNeo-Medium",
    "AppleSDGothicNeo-Bold",
    "AppleSDGothicNeo-UltraLight",
    "AppleSDGothicNeo-Regular"
)

Euphemia UCAS: (
    EuphemiaUCAS,
    "EuphemiaUCAS-Bold",
    "EuphemiaUCAS-Italic"
)
PingFang HK: (
    "PingFangHK-Regular",
    "PingFangHK-Medium",
    "PingFangHK-Thin",
    "PingFangHK-Semibold",
    "PingFangHK-Light",
    "PingFangHK-Ultralight"
)
Menlo: (
    "Menlo-BoldItalic",
    "Menlo-Italic",
    "Menlo-Regular",
    "Menlo-Bold"
)
Kailasa: (
    Kailasa,
    "Kailasa-Bold"
)
Khmer Sangam MN: (
    KhmerSangamMN
)
Avenir: (
    "Avenir-Book",
    "Avenir-Heavy",
    "Avenir-BlackOblique",
    "Avenir-Black",
    "Avenir-LightOblique",
    "Avenir-BookOblique",
    "Avenir-Light",
    "Avenir-Medium",
    "Avenir-HeavyOblique",
    "Avenir-Oblique",
    "Avenir-Roman",
    "Avenir-MediumOblique"
)
Savoye LET: (
    SavoyeLetPlain
)
Zapf Dingbats: (
    ZapfDingbatsITC
)
Kannada Sangam MN: (
    "KannadaSangamMN-Bold",
    KannadaSangamMN
)
Copperplate: (
    Copperplate,
    "Copperplate-Light",
    "Copperplate-Bold"
)
Gurmukhi MN: (
    GurmukhiMN,
    "GurmukhiMN-Bold"
)
Iowan Old Style: (
    "IowanOldStyle-Italic",
    "IowanOldStyle-Bold",
    "IowanOldStyle-BoldItalic",
    "IowanOldStyle-Roman"
)
Oriya Sangam MN: (
    "OriyaSangamMN-Bold",
    OriyaSangamMN
)
Helvetica: (
    "Helvetica-Oblique",
    "Helvetica-Bold",
    "Helvetica-LightOblique",
    "Helvetica-BoldOblique",
    "Helvetica-Light",
    Helvetica
)
```

Comment: Similar issue: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/21350

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code snippet to validate whether `Chalkduster` is a correct font name on tvOS:

```
NSArray *fontFamilies = [UIFont familyNames];
for (int i = 0; i < [fontFamilies count]; i++)
{
    NSString *fontFamily = [fontFamilies objectAtIndex:i];
    NSArray *fontNames = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:[fontFamilies objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSLog (@"%@: %@", fontFamily, fontNames);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I just posted another answer with the available font families.

Comment: @Reinaldo I think to paste the font family in your question as an update will help others find what they need more easily. Thanks let us know the difference on tvOS.